# Use regex on binary file in C++

Tags: c++, regex, binary

I have a little problem and don't know how to solve it exactly as I'm not that good with C++. :-(

I have a binary file where I want to extract the following as a txt file. Please note line 49 from the second link where the line says 1337 multiple times (this should be some delimiter). I wrote a [bashscript](http://sprunge.us/iANO?bash) which solves this task but I wanted to do it in C++ also.

Ideas and tips are welcome! If you don't understand what I want to know, please let me know, so I can explain my question more detailed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: C/C++ is not a language, and the answers are going to differ greatly.

Comment: Anyone who mentions both, usually prefers the C++ solution.  @domac: specifying is still a good diea.  If you have a choice, I highly recommend the C++ variant.

Comment: @ChrisCM, It looks that way here, but in my experience, it's usually omeone wanting a C solution and assuming C++ people know it because "they're the same language" or something.

Comment: Ok, so I'm fine with both. Nothing especially I prefer but I'm fine with c++. :-)
I fixed the title. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I know this is and old thread, but I had the same problem not long ago, so I want to contribute.

The easiest way to parse a binary file with the std::regex, in my experience, is using [sregex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).
But remember that you will need a compiler that fully implements c++11 (or at least the regex library). I am using GCC 4.9 and it works with regex (I believe Clang also works).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is void of specifics, so for now I will just supply you with a couple of references.  First is the C++ regex library, new in C++11.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

The second, and my preferred solution, is the boost regular expression library.  The boost libraries are very solid(most of them), and i recommend taking advantage of them in as many caases as you can, sometimes even over some of the STL containers, though research before doing so if performance is a concern.  Some of the boost extension containers are unstable in certain circumstances.  Below is a link for the boost regular expression library documentation.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

The reason I recommend boost is A: it is not dependant on C++11 support(reasonably standard by now, but by no means universal) and B: the boost regex library has been around for some time.  It is very solid.

EDIT: How to use the boost regex library

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {
    regex re("a.*");
    string passString = "asdasdfdasdfa";
    string failString = "babbddssddf";
    cmatch matches; //What this variable does is usually unimportant, read the documentation if you care to know.

    cout << passString << " " << regex_match(passString.c_str(), matches, re) << endl;
    cout << failString << " " << regex_match(failString.c_str(), matches, re) << endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
asdasdfdasdfa 1
babbddssddf 0
```

Built with the following command on my machine:

```
g++ some.cpp -I/opt/local/include  -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_regex-mt -o some
```

This command will depend on how you configure your boost installation.  There is also thorough documentation on doing a regex_search for global matching, and such on the documentation page, this is just meant to get you started.

Comment: Hey ChrisCM!

Thanks for your answer. I already tried the C++11 regex with no success. I dunno why but it didn't work. [Here is my try](http://sprunge.us/YITM?c++)

The Boost regex library was a bit too complicated for me… can you provide some example code? Thanks!